# Automating iOS Testing with PHP/Terminal

Tags: php, ios, bash, shell, automation

I'm attempting to create a Testing service that will run my iOS JS tests from a website.  For example, I go to my site, use PHP to create links for each of the .js files in a specific folder, and then click a link to start the test.  When I click the link I use PHP to run a bash .sh file on the machine.  The .sh file then runs the test.

If I run the .sh file locally it works great.  If I run it from my website, the simulator opens but the app doesn't ever open.  I receive an error stating that it timed out trying to find the simulator device.

Any ideas on why I can't get this working?

My php file contains this line to run the bash script:

```
$output = "<pre>" . shell_exec('sudo ./hello.sh 2>&1') . "</pre>";
```

I edited my visudo file to allow this hello.sh file to be run as sudo as well, before I did that I couldn't get the simulator to open at all.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to allow this in your sudoers file.

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/script/hello.sh
```

where www-data is the user as apache runs as.
Second. you need to have the full pathname in shell_exec.

```
$output = "<pre>" . shell_exec('sudo /path/to/script/hello.sh 2>&1') . "</pre>";
```

Not sure how the $PATH variable in your shell is used here, so can be that you must add the following to your hello script:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: I did
echo exec('whoami');
and the user was "www".


For running the hello.sh file changed my path using chdir to the correct location of the hello.sh file.  The hello.sh file runs, prints out what I set it to print out, and also starts the simulator up, it just doesn't start the app that it should on the simulator.

With that information do you still think the above changes will fix my issue?  I'll try it out now.


EDIT: Unfortunately that didn't solve it, the script still runs, opening the simulator as it was before, but no App opens.

Comment: Try using full path to all "programs" inside hello.sh. example for iptables would be `/sbin/iptables`

Comment: `instruments -t "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate" -w "iPad Retina (8.2 Simulator)" "myApp.app"  -e UIASCRIPT basicLogin.js -e UIARESULTSPATH . >> results.txt`



This is the line I'm running.  It opens the simulator, but not the app when trying to to it from PHP.  If I do it from terminal on my machine it works fine.

Comment: specify full path for `instruments`, `myApp.app`, `basicLogin.js` and `results.txt`